# retrieving ids with 'only' one type of code

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample of table:

```
ID     Code
2324    1
2324    2
2325    1
2326    1
2326    2
```

I want to get the id’s that only have code ‘1’ and not also code ‘2’ so the result would be

```
2325    1
```

Since the others have code’s 1 and 2

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE CODE != 1 AND CODE = 2
```

but that just returns any id's with code 2 regardless if the id also has code 1 or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.Code = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE ID = T.ID AND Code <> T.Code
)
```

Comment: I think you meant `T.Code = 1` :)

Answer (score 6):

```
select ID, min(code) from t1
group by ID 
having min(code) = 1 and max(code) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from myTable t1
where not exists(select 1 from myTable
                 where t1.id = id and Code <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select * from table t1 where Not exists 
( select 1 from table t2 where t1.id=t2.id and
  t2.code=2)

with cte as
(
select 2324 as id ,1 as code union all
select 2324 ,2
union all
select 2325,1
union all
select 2326,1 union all
select 2326 ,2
)
select * from cte t1 where Not exists 
( select 1 from cte t2 where t1.id=t2.id and
  t2.code=2)
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f1c57cadcc00482e9d65ef99e4acfad0)

```
 id     code
 2325    1
```

Comment: You mean NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE T.Code = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE ID = T.ID AND Code <> T.Code
)
```